# How to animate title in navbar?

Tags: jquery-animate, navbar, title

I have a title under a navbar. And when I scroll, the title supposed to animate into the navbar. I can't find anywhere to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery for detecting the scrolling
http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-jquery-scroll-based-animations/ or to set waypoints, which will trigger a function when the user scroll to an element http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks this helped